# How to put a few rows in between this loop?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm confused as to how to put a few rows in between this loop, like before it copies and pastes into the next row there should be an n number of rows between them.

```vb
Sub PasteSpecial_Examples()
  For i = 1 To 6
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("J1:V1").Copy
    Sheet4.Select
    Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
  Next i
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I tried putting + 2 on i, but it only worked on the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could manually loop through the range, instead of calling it's paste method:

http://codevba.com/excel/for_each_cell_in_range.htm#.XhR85GZMFhE

That way, you can advance the row counter however you like.

Comment: Hmmm I'm just trying to copy and paste J1:V1.. How do I apply that?

Comment: (J1:V1) is 13 cells horizontally, correct?
So the code should paste those 13 cells 6 times, once on each row, correct?
You stated you wanted a few rows in between each paste, correct?

It occurs to me that you could do 'For i = 1 to 12 Step 2' and that should skip a row each time.